# Can not turn off the raspberry 3 running Android Things

Tags: android, android-things

How can I turn off or turn a RaspberryPi 3 (using android things) apart from unplugging it? Thanks for any help and I do appreciate any kind of help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like any other Unix/Linux: **sudo init 0** or **sudo halt**.

This is actually a good practice, by removing power cable you can cause data loss or damage memory card.

Comment: Thank for your help, but it sound likes not similar on linux. Must using that command, it can work : "adb shell reboot -p"

Answer (score 0):

you wish to shutdown, use `sudo shutdown –h` now to immediately begin the system halt and shutdown process.

Comment: Thank for your help. I also tried that like in linux, but it's still not working. However, I already found that use that command can solve the problem: "adb shell reboot -p"